# How to write a macro using the AverageIFS condition for multiple criteria.?

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I am in the need of a macro which can handle multiple criteria to take the average.

1. Read the value in "Sheet1" ( say "5" is the value) - see the screenshot.
2. Once read, it should to go to the "Sheet2" to take average of column A for only the first "5" values --> since it read the 5 value in step 1.
3. Paste the average in "sheet3"

The last step if the value is greater than 5, then it has to return that value--> (e.g. if it is "7" --> then 7 should be returned, not the average.

I am unable to post the macro as i am just a beginner with this macro stuffs.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? I'm not going to write the whole thing for you! Just a hint though, you can use a variable e.g. `x` which would contain the number in `Sheet1.Range("A2")` then you can define the range in Sheet2 with `Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & x)` ...

Comment: i dont have a macro written. I can handle with simple macros, but handling this kind of condition. I really dont know. I know writing a macro just for me makes no sense.thanks for your hint let me try to explore....

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner sub routine you can have this:

```
Public Sub GET_AVERAGE()
   Sheet3.Range("A2").Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & Sheet1.Range("A2").Value2 + 1))
End Sub
```

This will place the average of sheet2 range A2:A`x` in to sheet3 range A2 - where `x` is defined by Sheet1.Range("A2").value (in your case, 5)